# Vector meaning within economics

Tags: microeconomics, price

So what does a vector mean in economics, in layman's terms?
For example,
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hicksian_demand_function

> where $h(p,\bar{u})$ is the Hicksian demand function, or commodity bundle demanded, at price vector p and utility level
> $\bar{u}$. Here p is a vector of prices, and x is a vector of quantities demanded, so the sum of all $p_ix_i$ is total expenditure on all goods.

Is a price vector here just a bundle of prices $(p_1, p_2, ..., p_n)$ that verifies vector space properties?

Answer (score 4):

The meaning is same as in mathematics.

Indeed price vector $\mathbf{p}$ is just:

$$\mathbf{p} = (p_1,p_2, ... , p_n)$$

Comment: Just to add onto this, vectors in economics are often column vectors by default. Thus it would be standard to write $p_i'x_i$ to denote the dot product of the two vectors representing total expenditures.